# Is there way to combine two SVGs with opacity and only show one SVG when they overlap?

Tags: svg, svg-filters

I want to fill the gap in the round-arrow line, and the round-arrow line with opacity less than 1. I achieved this in the following code snippet, but I noticed it causes an overlap problem. I'd like to remove the semi-circle overlap area. To do this, I attempted to blend the gap line with the round-arrow line.
However, I encountered an issue where the opacity of the round-arrow line affected the gap line. I simply want to eliminate the semi-circle and ensure that the opacity of the gap line is not influenced by the round-arrow line.
Is there a way to accomplish this goal? (Maybe the worst way is to mask the semi-circle...)
Here is my codepen demo: https://codepen.io/cactusxx/pen/gOqaQxQ

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <polyline id="p1" points="50,50 250,50" fill="none" stroke-width="10" stroke-linecap="round" />
    <mask id="m1" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <use href="#p1" stroke="white" />
      <use href="#p1" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="40 30" />
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <!--   blue gap line-->
  <use href="#p1" stroke="blue" mask="url(#m1)" />
  <!--   line with arrow -->
  <g opacity="0.5">
    <use href="#p1" stroke="rgb(255,0,0)" stroke-dasharray="40 30" />
    <!--     arrow -->
    <polygon id="arrowPoly" points="250,35 280,50 250,65" fill="rgb(255,0,0)" stroke="rgb(255,0,0)" stroke-width="5" stroke-linejoin="round" />
  </g>

</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <!--  Blend the blue line into the SourceGraphic. -->
    <polyline id="pp" points="50,50 250,50" fill="none" stroke-width="10" stroke="blue" stroke-linecap="round" />
    <filter id="blend" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <feImage x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#pp" result="backline" />
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="backline" mode="normal" />
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <g opacity="0.5" filter="url(#blend)">
    <use href="#p1" stroke="rgb(255,0,0)" stroke-dasharray="40 30" />
    <!--     arrow -->
    <polygon id="arrowPoly" points="250,35 280,50 250,65" fill="rgb(255,0,0)" stroke="rgb(255,0,0)" stroke-width="5" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
  </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: you can put the <polygon id="arrowPoly" inside the mask and <use> the arrowPoly at the end of your code. Also I would like to tell you that you may use a <marker> for the arrow.

Comment: Note that to do what @enxaneta said you'll need to set your `fill` differently, so that you can set it to black in the mask. The easiest might be to move the `fill` declaration on a parent `<g>`, so that the one on the `<use>` wins.

Comment: @enxaneta Thank you for your reply! I know how to use  to attach an arrow to the end of the line. I think my problem is that there will be an overlap when the arrow has an opacity less than 1. Please forgive me,  I don’t know how to eliminate this area using your method.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you very much for replying. I’m having some difficulty understanding how to implement your advice for my purpose. If you have the time, could you please provide a code example? I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

As I've commented *you can put the `<polygon id="arrowPoly"` inside the mask and `<use>` the arrowPoly at the end of your code.*

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <polyline id="p1" points="50,50 250,50" fill="none" stroke-width="10" stroke-linecap="round" />
    <mask id="m1" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <use href="#p1" stroke="white" />
      <use href="#p1" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="40 30" />
      <polygon id="arrowPoly" points="250,35 280,50 250,65"   /> 
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <!--   blue gap line-->
  <use href="#p1" stroke="blue" mask="url(#m1)" />
  <!--  line with arrow -->
 <g opacity=".5" >
    <use href="#p1" stroke="rgb(255,0,0)" stroke-dasharray="40 30" />
    <!--  arrow -->
   <use href="#arrowPoly" fill="rgb(255,0,0)"/>
  </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing this example! I didn't understand before why placing the <Polygon id=arrowpoly inside a <mask> and then using <use> to use the polygon achieves the effect of the arrow covering the blue line (even though the arrow has transparency). After looking at your code, I still don't understand the principle behind doing it this way. If you could briefly explain, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: when you are using the arrowpoly inside the mask it's filled black by default. You are filling it red only when used with <use>

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I found that if I set a round corner for the arrow by adding <use href="#arrowPoly" fill="rgb(255,0,0)" stroke-width="5" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke="rgb(255,0,0)">, then an overlap area will appear. You can see the effect on this link: [https://codepen.io/cactusxx/pen/MWLKpWb]. If you could give me some advice on how to revise it, I would appreciate it!

Comment: The example you have in codepen (broken link above) uses a filter and no mask. This would be a different question.

Comment: Sorry, this is the link: https://codepen.io/cactusxx/pen/MWLKpWb. I didn't describe my question clearly. My arrow is a round arrow, so I need to set the stroke.

Comment: I have resolved my issue by removing the overlapping part from the gap-fill line. You can observe the changes in this CodePen demo: https://codepen.io/cactusxx/pen/MWLKmyB . Thank you for your assistance and responses!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I resolved the issue of overlap by eliminating the overlapping area from the gap-fill line (Update: I've made the entire arrow in the gap-fill line invisible, so I don't need to calculate the points; I can simply use the same points as the arrow.). While this might not be the optimal solution, it currently fulfills my objective. If you have any alternative or better solutions, I would greatly appreciate your input!

Here is my solution:
https://codepen.io/cactusxx/pen/MWLKmyB

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <polyline id="p1" points="50,50 250,50" fill="none" stroke-width="10" stroke-linecap="round" />
    <mask id="m1" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <use href="#p1" stroke="white" />
      <use href="#p1" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="40 30" />
      <polygon points="250,35 280,50 250,65" stroke-width="5" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke="black" />
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <!--   blue gap -->
  <use href="#p1" stroke="rgb(0,0,0,0.8)" mask="url(#m1)" />
  <!--   line with arrow -->
  <g opacity="0.5">
    <use href="#p1" stroke="rgb(255,0,0)" stroke-dasharray="40 30" />
    <!--  round arrow -->
    <polygon id="arrowPoly" points="250,35 280,50 250,65" stroke-width="5" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke="rgb(255,0,0)" fill="rgb(255,0,0)" />
  </g>

</svg>
```